# When I try to make a DependencyProperty: Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement

Tags: mvvm, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am building a custom `DataGridColumn` by inheriting from `DataGridBoundColumn` but when I try to make a `DependencyProperty` this error appear in the output window

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=myViewModelProperty; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'CustomDataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=24500989); target property is
>   'ItemsSourcePath' (type 'Object')

I have read about DataContext in DataGridColumns and I have heard about that this objects do not belong to the Visual Tree. But I cannot find the way to make them inherit the DataContext from their Parent

This is the code I have used

```
    public partial class CustomGridComboBoxColumn : DataGridBoundColumn
    {
        //The value indicating where to get the itemsSource
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourcePathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "ItemsSourcePath",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(CustomGridComboBoxColumn));
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or set the related collection 
    /// </summary>
    public string ItemsSourcePath
    {
        get
        {
          return (string)GetValue(ItemsSourcePathProperty);
        }
        set
        {
           SetValue(ItemsSourcePathProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Then I have overriten the method to create the editing style

```
protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
            Binding binding = new Binding(ItemsSourcePath.ToString());
            binding.Source = (this.DataGridOwner as DataGrid).DataContext;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(comboBox, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty,
            binding);

            return comboBox;
        }
```

And I am trying to use it like this

```
<cc:CustomDataGridComboBoxColumn Header="New Column" ItemsSourcePath="{Binding myViewModelProperty}"/>
```